# Identify objectID of multiline to connect them in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, union

I have two sheets; in each there is a road network, but drawn by different people. Now I want to connect those lines that are intersected by the index sheets
as I shown below, but what I found is some them are having gaps between.

In this case I am not interested to complete it otherwise to merge it only.

[image: try]

Here what I think I should do is to select those line that intersect with the index boundary and then select the objectid of each two and union it as the code.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#get a list with all unique values in subtype field
subtypes=[]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("RoadCenterline", ["subtype"]) as sCursor:
    for row in sCursor:
        if not row[0] in subtypes:
            subtypes.append(row[0])

# loop through all subtypes
for st in subtypes:
    features=arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("RoadCenterline","NEW_SELECTION","subtype={0}".format(st))
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis("RoadCenterline", tempintersections, output_type="POINT")ID
```

and here is the code of the objectid that I define manualy not auto by which 2 line close togther.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
 
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("RoadCenterline",["SHAPE@"], "objectId=432") as uCursor:
     with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("RoadCenterline",["SHAPE@"], "objectId=442") as sCursor:
         row1 = uCursor.next() #get first record
         row2 = sCursor.next() #get first record
         geom = row1[0].union(row2[0])
         row1[0] = geom
         arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(geom,"in_memory\merged")
         uCursor.updateRow(row1) # TypeError: cannot read geometry sequence. expected list of floats

del uCursor
del sCursor
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```